# Fazendo uma função LINQ que possa ser chamado numa consulta no EF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

Tenho a seguinte expressão:

```
Where(cd => cd.Modal == modal)
    .Select(s => s.Volume)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
    .Sum()
```

que uso pára fazer um mesmo calculo diversas vezes dentro de algumas *querys* através do LINQ e tentei criar o seguinte *extension method*, porém ao executar minha consulta ele dá a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'system decimal
>   CalculateVolume'

Método:

```
public static decimal CalculateVolume(this IEnumerable<MyEntity> query, Modal modal)
{
    return query.Where(cd => cd.Modal == modal)
              .Select(s => s.Volume)
              .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
              .Sum();
}
```

Segue um exemplo de como tentei executar o comando:

```
var modal = 1;
_context.EntityTeste
    .Select(c => new
    {
        Current = c.MyEntity.CalculateVolume(modal)
    })
```

A entidade `MyEntity` é uma lista dentro da `EntityTeste`.

Como posso fazer para que eu consiga transformar esse trecho de código que é repetido diversas vezes numa instrução que o LINQ entenda e execute no banco de dados?

Comment: Acredito que nesses casos a melhor opção é o Dapper.

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann Como o Dapper poderia ajudar num caso destes?

Comment: @LINQ já tive um problema muito parecido e pra não carregar tudo em memória pra poder chamar o método fizemos uma função no BD e fizemos uma query usando a função usando o Dapper. Mas no meu caso era cálculos com data.

Comment: Mas pra fazer uma uma função no banco e chamar na query não precisaria do Dapper, certo? Dá pra fazer com o EF...

Comment: No EF6 isso é um pouco complicado e nem tudo funciona como deveria funcionar, no EF Core que houve um grande avanço nesse aspecto pode ser feito, o problema que eu não consegui visualizar qual SQL você precisa executar, [poderia editar a sua pergunta e exemplificar melhor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/386398/edit), está vago um pouco e do jeito que você fez ele não vai entender aquilo como uma expressão `Linq`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não vou afirmar que não seja possível fazer no SQL Server que suporta a criação de função com .NET, mas o processo não é tão trivial, e não estou dizendo que fica bom ou mesmo se dá mesmo. Em outros bancos de dados certamente não dá. Para executar no banco de dados este tem que suportar isto, não tem como um algoritmo escrito em C# magicamente vá para o banco de dados e execute lá.

Qualquer solução que use será executada na memória. Se estiver usando um `IQueryable` haverá uma conversão do que dá para uma consulta, possivelmente SQL porque deve estar usando um DB assim), que será enviada para o banco de dados e retornará os dados filtrados, mas sem a parte de filtro que ele não sabe como converter, aí os dados que vierem rodarão em memória fazendo o filtro do seu método gerando o resultado final do jeito que deseja.

Também não estou dizendo que não tem como fazer essa *query* dar o mesmo resultado totalmente em SQL escrevendo o LINQ de outra forma, mas parece que não.

De forma geral qualquer coisa que saia muito do trivial é melhor passar uma *query* SQL e evitar LINQ.

A questão do não reconhecimento deve ser por algo que não está no código apresentado, pode ser que o método não esteja disponível neste escopo mesmo. Mas não importa porque não fará o que deseja.

Answer (score 1):

Pesquisei um pouco e achei trechos dizendo que você deve usar `List<>` em função de trabalhar com objetos iteráveis.

Portanto, tente adicionar o método **ToList()** antes do `.Where`:

```
public static System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<decimal>> CalculateVolume(this IEnumerable<MyEntity> query, Modal modal)
{
    return () => { return query.ToList().Where(cd => cd.Modal == modal).Select(s => s.Volume).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum(); };
}
```

Isso irá carregar a sua tabela na memória, então, tome cuidado com pesquisas grandes.

Além disso, passei seu código para um `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<>>` e usei lambda para retornar o seu código.

Pesquisei sobre isso [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259567/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method).

Comment: Não quero ter que carregar o objeto em memória para fazer isso, quero fazer isso na query

Comment: Tente então só mudar o tipo de retorno do método.